# Upload Metadata with Multiple Files in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, file

I want to upload multiple files in laravel with metadata. Like file custom name and file category.

I tried to add some property in frontend using js but I can see them in the controller
here the code

```
$(document).on('change','#file',function(e){
  let file = e.target.files[0]

  file.totalWords = 1234;
  file.caytegory = 'category';
          
  filesList.push(file)
});

let mainFormData = new FormData();
    filesList.forEach(file => { 
      mainFormData.append('files[]',file)
    })


$.ajax({
      data: mainFormData,
      url: 'controller_url',
      type: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      headers: {
        Accept : "application/json"
    },
    success: function (data) {
       console.log(data)
      });
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

And here is my controller

```
return response()->json($request->file('files')[0]->caytegory);
```

What I want is just to access the category property from the submitted file but I cann't

Comment: Each file will have same category or can be different at the time of uploading

Comment: The user will select the category when uploading the file